# Mtp/Ptp Android

Tags: android, usb, mtp

I'm trying to copy the files of my camera who use PTP to my tablet. I have use the android API MTPDevice 
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/mtp/MtpDevice.html#importFile%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) , I have request necessary permission(android.mtp.MtpClient.action.USB_PERMISSION).

I have open the device, the  function return true, and open the USBConnection (Connexion OK).

I try to import all files of the camera in a temp Folder on my tablet (/mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder). The path exist on my tablet, but when i give it to the importFiles function I have the error :

[LOGCAT]

```
MtpDevice: readObject: /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder
MtpDevice: open failed for /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder
Debug: File import KO
```

I have try with a path doesn't exist I have the message :

[LOGCAT]

```
MtpDevice: readObject: /mnt/sdcard/tptp
MtpDevice: readResponse failed
Debug: File import KO
```

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

```
  @Background
@DebugLog
public void getMTPDevice() {
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    if (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        UsbDevice usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();
        device = openDeviceLocked(usbDevice);
        if(device!=null){
                File folder = returnTempFolderCamera();
                if(folder.exists()){
                    Log.d("Debug", "Folder exist /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder");
                    if(device.importFile(0,folder.getPath()))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "File import OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Debug", "Files import OK");
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "File import KO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("Debug", "Files import KO");
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}/**
 * Opens the {@link android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice} for an MTP or PTP device
 * and return an {@link android.mtp.MtpDevice} for it.
 *
 * @param usbDevice
 *            the device to open
 * @return an MtpDevice for the device.
 */
@DebugLog
private MtpDevice openDeviceLocked(UsbDevice usbDevice) {
    String deviceName = usbDevice.getDeviceName();
    byte[] data = new byte[128];
    int TIMEOUT = 0;
    boolean forceClaim = true;
    // don't try to open devices that we have decided to ignore
    // or are currently asking permission for
    if (isCamera(usbDevice)
            && !mRequestPermissionDevices.contains(deviceName)) {
        if (!manager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
            manager.requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent);
            mRequestPermissionDevices.add(deviceName);
        } else {
            UsbInterface intf = usbDevice.getInterface(0);
            UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
            UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(usbDevice);
            connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
            connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, data, data.length, TIMEOUT);
            if (connection != null) {
                MtpDevice mtpDevice = new MtpDevice(usbDevice);
                if (mtpDevice.open(connection)) {
                    mDevices.put(usbDevice.getDeviceName(), mtpDevice);
                    return mtpDevice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
        private File returnTempFolder(){
            File tmp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tmpFolder");
            return tmp;
        }
```

Comment: `have request necessary permission, and write in the manifest`. Which ones would that be? For the rest your post is pretty unclear when and where you hsve messages for which paths exactly.

Comment: `createTempFolderCamera()`. Wrong function name as it does not create a folder but only returns a File object for a folder.

Comment: `Log.d("Debug", "File exist");`. You mean 'folder exists' ?

Comment: "android.mtp.MtpClient.action.USB_PERMISSION"; for the permission.

Comment: I have the message for "/mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder" (the path exist) MtpDevice: readObject: /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder
MtpDevice: open failed for /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder and I have the other message for "/mnt/sdcard/tptp" who doesn't exist.

Comment: Which messages? I said that your post was unclear and you are only repeating yourself. That does not clear up anything. Please rephrase your post. Make it a decent story. And you did not react to all the things i ssid. So please do if you really want help. Edit your post instead of using comments.

Comment: There still is much unclear. As first remark you should never hard code such a log statement. `Log.d("Debug", "Folder exist /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder");`. Better change to `Log.d("Debug", "Folder exists: "+ folder.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: `MtpDevice: readObject: /mnt/sdcard/tmpFolder`. Please show the code fragment that produces this message. I do not understand why that function would try to read that folder where it should write files to.

Comment: `if(folder.exists()){` You have no log statement or Toast in case the folder does not exist. Why not? Why dont you inform the user correctly? And you have no code to create that folder. You only create a name. I said that before but you did not react.

Answer (score 1):

For people who have the same problem :

Solution is (Found on github) :

MtpClient (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/jb-dev/src/com/android/gallery3d/data/MtpClient.java)

```
@Background
@DebugLog
public void importFiles() {
    MtpClient mtpClient = new MtpClient(this);
    mtpClient.getDeviceList();
    for (int i = 0; i < mtpClient.getDeviceList().size(); i++) {
        int[] tab = mtpClient.getDeviceList().get(i).getObjectHandles(mtpClient.getDeviceList().get(i).getStorageIds()[0], 0, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
            File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // NAME_IMPORTED_FOLDER = tmpFolder
            dest = new File(dest, NAME_IMPORTED_FOLDER);
            dest.mkdirs();
            MtpObjectInfo objInfo = mtpClient.getDeviceList().get(i).getObjectInfo(tab[j]);
            if (objInfo != null) {
                String destPath = new File(dest, objInfo.getName()).getAbsolutePath();
                int objectId = objInfo.getObjectHandle();
                // Succes !!
                boolean result = mtpClient.getDeviceList().get(i).importFile(objectId, destPath);
            }
        }
    }
    mtpClient.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding above post,
I downloaded the github gallery3d project ,
and look into code of MtpClient.java, 
then I find the difference,

The code section from github

```
String destPath = new File(dest,objInfo.getName()).getAbsolutePath();
int objectId = objInfo.getObjectHandle();

boolean result = mtpClient.getDeviceList().get(i).importFile(objectId, destPath);
```

The point is 2nd parameter of importFile(objectId, destPath ) "destPath", need to include folder path + filename,  then filename should not be changed original filename

But in the origianl question author, you just set folder path
in 2nd parameter